# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql

I have run into this error with a MySQL database installed on lucid lynx 10.04 that was working fine.  The last activity carried out before this problem manifested was exporting a database back up using phpmyadmin.  Now any attempt to connect results in this error whether from the command line, phpmyadmin tool or php script.

Most of the answers to similar posted questions involve finding where the mysqld.sock file is created and modifying the my.cnf file to point to its locaion.  However I cannot see where the mysqld.sock file is created.

I have verified that mysql is running as a service and following one forum advice, typing 
`ps -fea | grep mysqld` results in the following:

```
rich      10796 8900 0 08:13 pts/1 00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
```

mysqld is shown in red.  The rest of the advice given is to use the above output line to locate the file and modify the my.cnf file accordingly. However I do not know how to interpret the above information to this effect - being a noobie to ubuntu I am in the unhappy position of usually not understanding what the purpose of command lines (often suggested without an explanation) is and what their results should be so am reduced to randomly typing them in from various similar forum questions in the hope that eventually one will have the desired effect without breaking the whole thing in the process.

Could anyone advise a step by step trouble-shooting guide to this problem?  Where should the file be ceated in Ubuntu? The path in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file is /var/run/mysqld/myslqd.sock.  I presume this must have been where the file was being created previously when it was working unless the my.cnf file has been changed by some sort of automatic update, which I wouldn't have thought so given a password is usually required in ubuntu before such changes are made.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Judging from the output of `ps -fea | grep mysqld`, you _do not_ have MySQL running.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the below steps .,

backup the my.cnf.,

change the socket location to different location .,.

restart the mysql with   #/etc/init.d/mysql restart

try to connect with new socket .

Comment: as far as I know, linux doesn't allow you to start mysql as that. It wants the `service mysqld [re]start` command.

Comment: Thanks to all who have responded so far.

Lanzz:  If I run service --status-list, mysql is shown with the symbol [?].  This corresponds to 'unknown'. I suppose I should be expecting [+].  If I run sudo initctl list, mysql is shown in the list of results with 'start/running'.  However there is no process number. Again I am not sure what I should be expecting.

tsabz: Sorry, not sure what you mean.

sandeep: Tried this but didn't work. The command for restart seemed to go off alright after a password prompt but there was no feedback.
T-Shirt Dude: this command line fails as unrecognised service.

Comment: Just to add have tried a command from ubuntu to check mysql status
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
This returns nothing, just goes to the next command prompt.
When using the sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart command a message contained in the my.cnf file is shown which starts "Rather than invoking init scripts..." and ends "start: Job is already running: mysql"

The command 'service mysql restart' results in command unrecognised and the command 'sudo service mysql restart' hangs. Still none the wiser.

Comment: ....after a complete reboot due to the command 'sudo service mysql restart' hanging, normal service has resumed and everything is running again.  Had tried rebooting several times before to no effect so it seems the last command I tried shifted something.

Guess its just one of those things - two evenings of my life I will never get back and probably will never know why. Computers suck.